# How to find which dependency source in Cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

In my `Podfile` are only few pods linked, and some of them have sub-pods (as dependencies).

Is it possible to find out, which of my pods are linked with particular pod, which I haven't specified in `Podfile`?

Answer (score 1):

I found useful utility https://github.com/segiddins/cocoapods-dependencies

Using it like `pod dependencies` will print dependency tree.